# How do I use a for loop to get file names and then use them?

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, text-files

I have a folder with the files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt in it.  and I want to use a for-loop to get the names of these files, store them in a variable, and then add them to another text file.  The text files are located in the same file as my bat file.  Is it possible to do this? If so please show me, these for loops confuse the crap out of me...

What i have now

```
  @echo on

  SET name=hey
  echo >text.txt

  for %F in (*.*) do (set name=@fname
  echo name >> text.txt)
```

Comment: What's that: `The text files are located in the same file as my bat file.` The file is located in a file ??

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

(For %%# in ("*.txt") do (
    Set "FileName=%%~n#"
    Call Echo %%FILENAME%%
))>"MyFilenames.txt"

Pause&Exit
```

NOTE 1: Files are stored in "Filename" var, but is not really necessary, you can directly write the filename to the textfile.

NOTE 2:If you want a recursive loop through files use the /R switch of For command.

NOTE 3:If you want also the file extension change this: "%%~n#" to this else: "%%~nx#"

```
**UPDATE:**
```

**An alternative script:**

```
@Echo OFF
For %%# in (*.txt) do (Echo %%~n#>> "MyFiles.txt")
Pause&Exit
```

Comment: this just printed a text file that said "ECHO is on".  is it going thru a folder and getting filenames or thru a file and getting lines?

Comment: The script works, it goes thu the working folder where is it launched and getting filename of files, if you want to read the filenames of lines of textfile contents then at least post a example of the text file content, we are not wizards!

Comment: no that is doing exactly what i want it to do but when i put it in a new bat file it prints "MyFilenames" nothing else

Comment: Ok sorry, but It's too strange... the first code don't have any strange and it will works, anyway I've posted another way to do it, see my update, that code worked for me too.